# Subdomain in .htaccess file only works with index

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have a subdomain setup in my `.htaccess`, which only seems to work with the default `index.html` page. I'd LIKE it to work for ANY page in the folder corresponding to the subdomain. Edited for privacy, assume my domain is `example.org`. The pertinent parts of the file look like this...

```
#subdomain 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subname\.example\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subname\.example\.org$
# (a few lines added by my hosting company deleted -- see below)
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.org\/subname\/" [R=301,L]
```

So the result of the above is that if I have an `index.html` page in my 'public-html' (root?), `http://example.org` and a different `index.html` stored in a sub-folder (having the same name as the subdomain), I will get this expected result, which works...

browse to: `http://example.org`  results in viewing `http:// example.org/index.html`
browse to: `http://subname.example.org` results in viewing `http:// example.org/subname/index.html`

Great so far. This is what I expected when I created the domain name. However, given a specific file `myfile.html` stored in the `subname` folder, I would expect this to work also, and it doesn't...

browse to: `http://subname.example.org/myfile.html` results in a 404 error.

This despite the fact that browsing to `http://example.org/subname/myfile.html` works fine. In that case `myfile.html` is displayed. So is there anything I can do to modify the subdomain code to get the result I'm looking for? Namely, browsing to `http://subname.example.org/ANYFILE` should work as well as browsing to `http://example.org/subname/ANYFILE`, regardless of what 'ANYFILE' is. This, after all, is one of the main reasons I set up the subdomain to begin with!

Note: I confess that I relied on my hosting company's cPanel utility to create the subdomain code, so I asked for their tech support for help first. Long story short they didn't. Maybe what I hoped for is not actually possible?

Also, the lines I deleted' from the code had to do with something called "well-known/acme-challenge", added by my hosting company at some point. Since removing them had no effect on the behavior I've described, I left it out to avoid clouding the issue.

Comment: `.htaccess` is all lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.org\/subname\/" [R=301,L]
> ```

This only "redirects" the document root. To redirect all URLs you need to change the above to read something like:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.org/subname/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `$1` backreference refers to the URL-path captured in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. `(.*)`.

No need to backslash-escape the colons, slashes and dots in the *substitution* string (that's typical of cPanel).

> Also, the lines I deleted' from the code had to do with something called "well-known/acme-challenge", added by my hosting company at some point.

Those lines will likely be required when the (Let's Encrypt?) SSL cert auto-renews. (Although the above redirects to "http" - are you not using HTTPS?)

---

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subname\.example\.org$ [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subname\.example\.org$
> ```

Just as an aside, these two conditions could be reduced to a single condition if you wanted. For example, the above is equivalent to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subname\.example\.org$
```

Comment: Yes, its an old site (not https yet). But anyway, 1st thanks for clearing why all those escapes were added. Also, forgive my previous comment (just deleted!) Your suggestion seems to be working! It does NOT seem to interfere with accessing files in the document root, at http://domain/SOMEFILE. And, as hoped, a file in 'domain/sub/" can now be fetched with HTTP://sub/domain/SOMEFILE! I'll also have you know I've been back and fourth with tech support on this for days, and none of them could help. Sadly, I guess if it can't be done through CPANEL, the don't know where to begin. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, since I've not yet embarked on making my site HTTPS, I'm not sure why all those other lines were added. And all this has made me very leery of using the CPANEL when I *DO* decide to go to https. But for now I probably don't need those lines, so I've saved off the old htaccess, and left them out of the fixed version. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, hosting support generally won't deal with `.htaccess` queries. (Although sometimes only the web host will know the correct directive to use in certain cases.) The web host may have enabled the SSL cert by default (a drive towards "HTTPS everywhere"), at which point those _conditions_ are (annoyingly) injected before every `RewriteRule` directive. See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/884922/49157) to the following [ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/884915/apache-htaccess-multiple-rewrite-conditions-for-multiple-rules) for more info on this.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an optional extra to "simplify" those two conditions.

Comment: Thanks again, and indeed I probably did not need the second line (the 'OR' condition) in my REWRITECOND, because immediately before that I long ago added a rule to remove the "www" from requests. I did that after a maddening debugging sprint revealed that JavaScript cookies set when a visitor was there with WWW.MYDOMAIN were not the same as cookies set from a MYDOMAIN visit. Apparently this has happened a lot,  as I've been to medical sites that could not find my records unless I visited with WWW! So re-writing without the WWW was my solution. Still, I needs a GOOD how-to .HTACCESS book!

Comment: "JavaScript cookies set when a visitor was there with WWW.MYDOMAIN were not the same as cookies set from a MYDOMAIN visit." - that's arguably a fault of the JS, failing to properly set the domain on which the cookie is set. Although if you are importing 3rd party JS code then this may be tricky to code for unless the cookie domain can be explicitly stated in some config file.

Comment: Thanks, and I think I did discover a way, but as I'm SLOWLY learning to control more site-wide behavior in various .htacess files, I'm leaning that way more. As a plain vanilla JavaScript' user most of the time, I spend a great deal of time tweaking my libraries to accommodate different browsers, often missing some variations. OTOH, a solution in an .htaccess file, once placed, seems to continue working properly indefinitely, regardless of browser  evolution. Know any good reference books for htaccess, that fit what I call the ELIF category? :-)

Comment: "ELIF"? I have seen "The Definitive Guide to Apache mod_rewrite by Rich Bowen" referenced by others, but I have not read it myself. It would seem to be specifically "mod_rewrite", rather than ".htaccess". (And maybe a bit dated? 2006?) My goto resource is the (official) Apache docs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) - although not everyone's cup of tea - very concise with few examples. (The section on "Apache Expressions" is particularly lacking.)

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it. htaccess is one of those things which unlike my more frequent javaScript and PHP coding is not  used frequently enough for me to do anything successfully without some guidance. And to be honest, regular expressions still often confuse me. Thus I often paste in solutions without 100% understanding, which is something I HATE to do. Thus I look for ELIF explanations, which is one of those silly acronyms meaning "Explain Like I'm Five". I believe it started with a website using that acronym, inviting people to ask questions and get easy to follow answers. :-)